# Problem running KNI example program on RHEL 8 over vmware

Tags: vmware, rhel, dpdk

Previously, I can successfully run the "kni" example program in DPDK (version 20.08) on RHEL 8 over KVM (with the ethernet driver 'virtio-pci').

Then I changed to run this "kni" on RHEL 8 over vmware (with the driver 'vmxnet3'). If I started this "kni" to use 2 ports:

> ./kni -c 0x1f -n 4 -- -P -p 0x3 --config="(0,1,2),(1,3,4)"

It hanged when initializing the *2nd* port (initializing the 1st port is OK).

If it is started to use 1 port only:

> ./kni -c 0x07 -n 4 -- -P -p 0x1 --config="(0,1,2)"

It could start successfully but hanged when I killed this program (using kill -9).

Actually, I am not sure the VM hanged or not because all network interfaces were gone when the program "hanged" -- I was forced to log out since I connected to the VM by a SSH session.

It seems DPDK doesn't work quite well on RHEL 8 if it is over vmware (using 'vmxnet3'). It is suspected that there may be some problem with the 'vmxnet3' driver.

Anyone can successfully run DPDK (20.08) KNI application on RHEL 8 over vmware ?

Comment: how many cores are `pinned` to your VM? with 2 port application you have passed as `0x1f` so do you have `5` CPU inside your VM? In your question you have made a remark `seems DPDK doesn't work quite well on RHEL 8 if it is over vmware (using 'vmxnet3')`. As far I recollect DPDK PMD over `vmxnet3` and `KNI` are 2 different PMD, just like PCIe pass through is dffierent PMD for physical nic and KNI. So can you elobrate and explain the 2 items.

Comment: Since you have 2 ports have you enabled `kthread_mode=multiple`? and have pinned to lcore thread `lcore_kthread`? waiting for your updates

Comment: Yes, I understand that KNI and vmxnet3 are 2 different PMD. There are 8 cores so the number of cores is not a problem.
As I have said, I can successfully run the same program with the same command line arguments on RHEL 8 over KVM (no matter I start it with 1 port or 2 ports). It just failed (hanged or some other problems) on RHEL 8 over vmware, that's why I suspect the problem is 'vmxnet3' PMD.
Ignoring the 2 port case, even for the 1 port case, the program made the OS hanged when I killed the program (which didn't happen on RHEL 8 over KVM).

Comment: I recommend to update the ticket with relevant information, like kernel version, a number of cores, dmesg, syslog and dpdk logs (turned on to level 8 for PMD). I will wait for your updates.